# Accessing Capacitance Data From iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5

I thought it'd be really fun to make an app that takes advantage of the capacitive sensing ability of the iPhone screen.  Is there anyway we can access that data?  Are there any core libraries I should begin looking at?  It seems like it'd be hard to test in the simulator also.

I've heard of people accessing accelerometer data for sure...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is away to access such data even with private APIs. The functionality is not exposed in any way.

The accelerometer is exposed in an API, so it is a different story.

Comment: crap! maybe i should get comfortable writing android apps so I can try there.  do you happen to know if you can access that data on any android phones?